# How do remove the border around a core-plot graph

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am trying to remove the border around a core plot graph on the iPhone - but seem to be struggling on what should be simple in my mind.

Pointers please!

Comment: I am sorry if this is an obvious question but what is a core plot graph?

Comment: Core Plot is a library for graphing on the mac and on the iphone:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should be able to nil out the borderLineStyle on the graph's plotArea to remove the border:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;    // don't draw a border
```

You could also create your own theme, using the ones in the framework as examples, and simply not set the borderLineStyle in that.

Comment: If you are using a built-in theme, make sure you set the borderLineStyle AFTER the applyTheme call, or it'll get overwritten.

Comment: This comment is golden! Thanks! I had some testcode and just switched themes via a button. So everything got overwritten!

Comment: Just to add to Brad's answer. Please add the line mentioned in the answer after applying the theme. If you add it before that then it won't work.

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers worked for me. This did the job:

```
graph.paddingLeft = 0;
graph.paddingRight = 0;
graph.paddingTop = 0;
graph.paddingBottom = 0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderWidth = 0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

OK I found out how to do it - quite simple really!

```
CPLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor whiteColor];
borderLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;

graph.plotArea.borderLineStyle = borderLineStyle;
```

where graph is your graph object - the reason I had a border in the first place was because I used CPPlainWhiteTheme.

Hope this helps others - is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can set any line style to `nil`. This will cause the line to not be drawn at all.

Answer (score 1):

In CorePlot 1.0, the structure of `CPTGraph` has changed slightly. The code for removing the border line of a graph, assuming that `graph` is of type `GPTGraph` or a subclass of `CPTGraph`, is

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way with borderLineStyle = nil after applyTheme:

```
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostView.bounds];

// Set padding for plot area
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you are looking to not just remove the border line, but to make a plot that takes up the entire hosting view, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993792/132542) from [Thomas Johannesmeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277898/thomas-johannesmeyer) got me on the right track.

Here's what I did:

```
CPTGraphHostingView* hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
CGRect bounds = hostingView.bounds;

CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
hostingView.hostedGraph     = graph;

graph.paddingTop    = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.paddingRight  = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.paddingBottom = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.paddingLeft   = CPTFloat(0.0);

graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = CPTFloat(0.0);
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy      = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.title = nil;
CPTXYAxis *y          = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy      = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.title = nil;
```