# Weird border on Core Plot Pie Chart

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

Why is Core Plot drawing these two lines?

[image: ios graph]

This is how I'm setting up the graph:

```
// setup the pie chart
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:[_pieView bounds]];
[_pieView setHostedGraph:graph];

CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
[pieChart setDataSource:self];
[pieChart setPieRadius:75.0];
[pieChart setIdentifier:@"PieChart1"];
[pieChart setStartAngle:M_PI_4];
[pieChart setSliceDirection:CPTPieDirectionClockwise];

[graph addPlot:pieChart];
```

(`_pieView` is the `CPTGraphHostingView*`)

How do I remove the two black lines? I tried doing what's described in [How do remove the border around a core-plot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194290/how-do-remove-the-border-around-a-core-plot-graph), to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a border—it's the default axes that come with a `CPTXYGraph`. It's one line of code to remove them:

```
graph.axisSet = nil;
```

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense... I somehow forgot that I was using the `CPTXYGraph` to hold the pie chart. Anyway, thanks :)